# How can we keep index of pandas dataframe from generator?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following piece of code, which is used for creating a dataframe and inserting value into it.
    import string
    from numpy import nan
    from pandas import DataFrame

```
NRFINAL = ['I am a boy', 'He is a boy', 'ram is a boy']
TERM_COLUMN = []
#SENTENCE_ROW = []
for i in NRFINAL:
    for j in i.split():
        if j not in TERM_COLUMN:
            TERM_COLUMN.append(j)
FREQUENCY = {}
DF = DataFrame(index= [i for i in NRFINAL], columns=TERM_COLUMN)
for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    for j in index.split():
        for k in TERM_COLUMN:
            if j == k:
                count = FREQUENCY.get(k, 0)
                FREQUENCY[k] = count + 1
                DF.set_value(index, k, FREQUENCY[k])
    FREQUENCY.clear()
DF.replace(nan, 0, inplace=True)    # To replace nan value in dataframe cell
DF = DF.loc[~DF.apply(lambda row: (row == 0).all(), axis=1)]
MATRIX = DF.values.tolist()   #dataframe to list
print(MATRIX)
```

I am getting empty matrix as an output as shown below.

```
[]
```

But when I replace the same piece of code with:

```
import string
from numpy import nan 
from pandas import DataFrame
NRFINAL = ['I am a boy', 'He is a boy', 'ram is a boy']
TERM_COLUMN = []
SENTENCE_ROW = []
for i in NRFINAL:
    SENTENCE_ROW.append(i)
    for j in i.split():
        if j not in TERM_COLUMN:
            TERM_COLUMN.append(j)
print(TERM_COLUMN)
FREQUENCY = {}
DF = DataFrame(index= (SENTENCE_ROW), columns=TERM_COLUMN)
for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    for j in index.split():
        for k in TERM_COLUMN:
            if j == k:
                count = FREQUENCY.get(k, 0)
                FREQUENCY[k] = count + 1
                DF.set_value(index, k, FREQUENCY[k])
    FREQUENCY.clear()
DF.replace(nan, 0, inplace=True)    # To replace nan value in dataframe cell
DF = DF.loc[~DF.apply(lambda row: (row == 0).all(), axis=1)]
MATRIX = DF.values.tolist()   #dataframe to list
print(MATRIX)
```

I am getting the required output as shown below:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
```

What is the problem with the above code. Also, is there a way to optimize the above piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure why your first and second set of code behaves differently, as when i tried they both give the same result.
Please check out the below with less number of lines of code.

```
from collections import Counter
from pandas import DataFrame

NRFINAL = ['I am a boy', 'He is a boy', 'ram is a boy']
TERM_COLUMN = list(set(' '.join(NRFINAL).split()))
print(TERM_COLUMN)
DF = DataFrame(index= (NRFINAL), columns=TERM_COLUMN)
for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    for k in TERM_COLUMN:
        DF.set_value(index, k,(Counter(index.split()))[k])
MATRIX = DF.values.tolist()
print(MATRIX)
print(DF)
```

Comment: Thanks Aneesh. You are correct, that both code works. Once, I restart the IDE and run the same program again, It works.

Comment: can't we assign the TERM_COLUMN in dataframe column without making it a list?